# Bash variable formats

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

What are the differences between the following variables in regards to scripting with BASH:

```
$var
```

```
"$var"
```

```
${var}
```

```
"${var}"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference between `$var` and `${var}` and there is no difference between `"$var"` and `"${var}"`, except that in certain cases the parser may not be able to identify your intent when you user the former versions. Consider:

```
foo=hello
echo "$fooworld"
echo "${foo}world"
```

The first `echo` prints nothing, because the variable `fooworld` is not defined. The second prints `helloworld` because the shell was able to determine that you were referencing the `foo` variable.

The difference between `$var` and `"$var"` is that unquoted variable expansions are evaluated by the shell after the expansion. As such:

```
var='ls /'
$var
```

Lists `/`, because after the expansion the shell evaluates the space as a token separator, whereas

```
var='ls /'
"$var"
```

Results in `ls /: No such file or directory` because no command named `ls /` is available in the user's environment.

Answer (score 2):

The ones in quotes are expanded to a single parameter and not chopped up into separate words.

The `${var}` notation is useful if the next character could be part of the variable name, eg: `"${var}name"`.

```
function args() {
  while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do echo "arg: '$1'"; shift; done
}

# var=" a b  c"

# args $var
arg: 'a'
arg: 'b'
arg: 'c'

# args "$var"
arg: ' a b  c'
```

Comment: Is it inappropriate to use the **${var}** notation at all times? Would this or could this cause issues depending on if the variable was a command E.g. **var=$(echo hi)** or if the variable was a simple string E.g **var="hi"** ?

Comment: "variable was a command" - you mean the variable was set to contain the *output* of a command? no, there's no difference. it's just a variable

Comment: It is always appropriate to use the `${var}` form, unless you think that it will hurt readability.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I did actually mean "the output of a command", thank you for the help and clarification.

Comment: @Sorpigal Thanks for the help. I personally like the way **${var}** looks while reading my scripts.