# What is the difference when using double quotes and not..?

Tags: bash

My code is fairly straightforward and just output is different from one another. And, I'd like to know why the result is showing like this..

```
#!/bin/bash

fileList=`ls`  
echo $fileList   # without doubleQuote
```

**output :**

```
f1 f2 f3
```

```
#!/bin/bash

fileList=`ls` 
echo "$fileList" # with doubleQuote
```

**output :**

```
f1 
f2
f3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that double-quotes disable *word splitting*. For example, if the variable `foo` contains `a  b  c`, then `"$foo"` is a single argument (equivalent to `'a  b  c'`), whereas `$foo` is split into three arguments (equivalent to `'a' 'b' 'c'` or simply `a b c`).

In your example, `fileList` contains newlines, which double-quotes preserve, whereas `echo $fileList` means `echo f1 f2 f3` — so it just prints spaces between them, which is what `echo` does when you give it multiple arguments.

Another difference, not applicable to your example but important in general, is that double-quotes disable *filename expansion*. For example, if the variable `foo` contains `a*`, then `echo "$foo"` will print `a*`, whereas `echo $foo` will print the names of all the files in the current directory that start with `a`.

You should almost *always* put your variable expansions in double-quotes; too many things can go wrong if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

From an answer to a similar question on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10388784/434551)

> The difference between `$var` and `"$var"` is that unquoted variable expansions are evaluated by the shell after the expansion. As such:

```
var='ls /'
$var
```

> Lists /, because after the expansion the shell evaluates the space as a token separator, whereas

```
var='ls /'
"$var"
```

> Results in `ls /: No such file or directory` because no command named `ls /` is available in the user's environment.